# Crash report. Can you help me with this crash?

Tags: flutter, dart, crash-reports

I have a Flutter project which has very simple functionality it basically has an `AppBar` and a `WebView` [Here is the link for this dependency](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)

Here is what I have so far

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(Almahdyoon());

class Almahdyoon extends StatelessWidget {
  const Almahdyoon({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WebViewController _controller;

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Almahdyoon"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: PageView(
            children: <Widget>[
              WebView(
                initialUrl: 'https://almahdyoon.com',
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  _controller = webViewController;
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the `Crash Report`

```
W/System.err( 3827): java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy0 cannot be cast to android.view.WindowManagerImpl
W/System.err( 3827):    at android.view.Window.setWindowManager(Window.java:793)
W/System.err( 3827):    at android.view.Window.setWindowManager(Window.java:775)
W/System.err( 3827):    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:207)
W/System.err( 3827):    at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:204)
W/System.err( 3827):    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:1105)
W/System.err( 3827):    at qy.<init>(PG:6)
W/System.err( 3827):    at org.chromium.content.browser.input.SelectPopup.show(PG:12)
W/System.err( 3827):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err( 3827):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
W/System.err( 3827):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
W/System.err( 3827):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7506)
W/System.err( 3827):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err( 3827):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
W/System.err( 3827):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:956)
F/chromium( 3827): [FATAL:jni_android.cc(249)] Please include Java exception stack in crash report
F/libc    ( 3827): Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 3827 (mple.almahdyoon), pid 3827 (mple.almahdyoon)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86_arm:R/RPP1.200123.019/6239754:userdebug/dev-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
Timestamp: 2020-04-29 08:38:56+0300
pid: 3827, tid: 3827, name: mple.almahdyoon  >>> com.example.almahdyoon <<<
uid: 10159
signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: '[FATAL:jni_android.cc(249)] Please include Java exception stack in crash report
'
    eax 00000000  ebx ca629aa8  ecx 00000081  edx 7fffffff
    edi ffd23110  esi ec4596c4
    ebp ffd23590  esp ffd23110  eip c62ee3ff
backtrace:
      #00 pc 008493ff  /product/app/TrichromeLibrary/TrichromeLibrary.apk!libmonochrome.so (offset 0x665000) (BuildId: d06485c6257dc0307dac1d873bb515827815a934)
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Can you help me solve this in Flutter? I saw articles on how to solve this in Android/Java but haven't in Flutter

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when using the AVD emulator. The solution is to be able to use the emulator again by wipe data via the menu AVD Manager > Actions > Wipe Data